# How exciting formula P=i^2r=vi=v^2/r is? How to use them efficiently while doing sophisticated problems?

Tags: electric-current

I have nowhere read about the way the expression P=i^2r=vi=v^2/r is used? At some pints it is taken as i^2r and at other vi. How to be sure about the use of this expression.

Answer (score 1):

> At some pints it is taken as i^2r and at other vi. How to be sure
>   about the use of this expression.

For *any* two-terminal circuit element $A$ with voltage across $V_A$ and current through $I_A$, the power associated with the circuit element is just their product:

$$P_A = V_A\cdot I_A$$

It is *only* in the case that the circuit element is an (ideal) resistor that

$$P_R = V_R\cdot I_R = I^2_R\cdot R = \frac{V^2_R}{R}$$

This is because of the fact that if you know the resistance $R$ and the voltage across (current through), you *know* via Ohm's law the current through (voltage across)

$$V_R = R\cdot I_R $$

That is, the voltage across and current through are *not* independent when the circuit element is a resistor.